# How to compare 2 images ignoring areas

Tags: imagemagick

I have a set of regression tests that take automatically take screenshots from my iPhone application.

I am using Imagemagick to compare the screenshot with a saved reference screenshot.

Simply:

```
$ compare -metric AE new.png ref.png diff.png
0
```

But, some areas of the screen are not of interest to this test and I want to ignore them (eg: menu panels, status icons, etc).

I would like to blank out these areas in my ref image. Ideally, and most simply, I just draw transparent blocks around the areas I don't want to compare.

But how can I tell imagemagick to ignore those transparent areas?

This extracts out the alpha area and generates BLACK for transparent and white for else:

```
$ convert ref.png -alpha extract ref_mask.png
```

Better is this makes white for alpha, and black for everything else:

```
$ convert ref.png -alpha extract -negate ref_mask.png
```

Can I combine that mask with the compare?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with your idea of using transparency in your reference image to mask the areas of interest. You need to use `bash` process substitution to solve this - whereby the output of a command is made to look like a file to another command. So you want to `diff` the first three lines of two files, you would do this:

```
diff <(head -3 file1) <(head -3 file2)
```

and the outputs of the two `head` commands in the two `<(...)` each look like a `file` to `diff`.

So, with ImageMagick, you want something like this:

```
compare -metric AE <(convert input.png ref.png -compose copy-opacity -composite png:) ref.png diff.png
```

So, look at the part in `<()` first. It says to take the file `input.png` and replace its transparency with that of your reference image `ref.png`. The result is then forced to be of type `PNG` and written on `stdout`. Then the `convert` command actually sees this:

```
compare -metric AE <file containing masked input.png> ref.png diff.png
```

Here is my `ref.png` (don't try using this actual image because I have made checkerboard artificially to show transparency on SO)

[image]

and `b.png`

[image]

and `c.png`

[image]

So, if I run these, I get this:

```
compare -metric AE <(convert b.png ref.png -compose copy-opacity -composite png:) ref.png diff.png
0


compare -metric AE <(convert c.png ref.png -compose copy-opacity -composite png:) ref.png diff.png
3245
```

That is, `b.png` is the same as the reference image because the blue squares lie in the transparent area.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look on ImageMagick **compare** [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php), you can use compare comand with the flag

```
-extract geometry   //extract area from image
```

Comment: No that's not so useful as it would require specifying all the regions by rects. That would be very time consuming. The work-flow i have in mind is simply editing the reg image and blocking out unrelated areas. There could be a dozen areas to remove for example. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm interested in the same thing, but I want to ignore areas outside of a circular selection...

Answer (score -4):

Take a look at [Visual CI](http://visualci.com)

It's a software built to compare images in continuous integration.
It allows you (using UI) to select which parts of the images should be compared.